# Difference between Django's __search vs. __icontains

Tags: django, full-text-search

I've started learning Django very recently, so please forgive me if this is too newbie a question for you.

I have a search function implemented in Django. I created in MySQL DB full-text-index and then have a field in my, say, Book model: `search_keywords`, where I basically store all the words including the title and the content of the book. Then my search function does something similar to this:

```
search_keyword = self.request.GET.get('keywords')
    if search_keyword:
        # '*' is added for cases where user enters only part of the keyword
        qs = qs.filter(keywords__search=search_keyword + '*')
```

But the above approach doesn't work if my search query is 'intro' where I know there's a word/term like 'test.introduction' (if the term is just 'introduction' then it works fine).

Then when I try this instead:

```
        qs = qs.filter(keywords__icontains=search_keyword)
```

it finds 'test.introduction' etc.

So I begin to wonder why this is the case. Is '__search' only for full-word searches? I know the case for '__icontains' makes sense (case-insensitive and contains part of the word), but why take trouble to create full-text-indexes in the DB just so we can use '__search' in Django? Is that the speed advantage (e.g., in cases of huge volumes of texts to search? Or am I missing something completely here?

Comment: A different is, `__search` doesn't work with `JSON_FIELD`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference is about the resulting SQL Query to be executed on the database... I personally prefer "__icontains" because is supported for all databases, and "__search" only for mysql ([as django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#search)) (*also supporting PostgreSQL in Django ≥ 1.10* — see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)).

Look at the query for each method:

**Using __search**

```
>>> str(Contact.objects.filter(first_name__search='john').query)

'SELECT `contact_contact`.`id`, `contact_contact`.`title`, `contact_contact`.`first_name`, `contact_contact`.`last_name`, `contact_contact`.`user_id`, `contact_contact`.`role_id`, `contact_contact`.`organization_id`, `contact_contact`.`dob`, `contact_contact`.`email`, `contact_contact`.`notes`, `contact_contact`.`create_date` FROM `contact_contact` WHERE MATCH (`contact_contact`.`first_name`) AGAINST (john IN BOOLEAN MODE)'
```

**Using __icontains**

```
>>> str(Contact.objects.filter(first_name__icontains='john').query)

'SELECT `contact_contact`.`id`, `contact_contact`.`title`, `contact_contact`.`first_name`, `contact_contact`.`last_name`, `contact_contact`.`user_id`, `contact_contact`.`role_id`, `contact_contact`.`organization_id`, `contact_contact`.`dob`, `contact_contact`.`email`, `contact_contact`.`notes`, `contact_contact`.`create_date` FROM `contact_contact` WHERE `contact_contact`.`first_name` LIKE %john% '
```

Comment: Thanks, @Darwin! That explains a lot. I also learned how to check the underlying queries of Django from you. :)

Comment: This can be a little miss leading...as __icontains is not considered to be a full text search.

Comment: At least for PostgreSQL there is a NotImplementedError if I try __search and the complete error message is "Full-text search is not implemented for this database backend". Django version 1.8

Comment: @user1330974
Is there an easy way to check the underlying queries that Django is running ?

Comment: @akki Sorry, I am also fairly new to Django, so I do not know the answer to your question. Hope you find it somewhere. :)

Comment: @user1330974 Ohh...I thought you said in this comment that you learnt it from Darwin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799919/difference-between-djangos-search-vs-icontains/22800227?noredirect=1#comment34815012_22800227

Comment: @akki, Ah...I see what you mean! What I said to him was that I learned to see the equivalent SQL statement that Django creates in the background for us by doing `str(YourModelName.objects.filter(attributeName__search='something').query)`. That's pretty much all. You can see it in Darwin's example above, too. Hope that helps??

Comment: Don't know how I missed that part of the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

as I tried, `__search` works just for whole word within multiple words (Incredible!), for example when my `Book` model contains an object with `title='The little prance'`, while

> Country.objects.filter(name__contais='itt')

returns one object,

> Country.objects.filter(name__search='itt')

return nothing!

Comment: This might be related to the underlying algorithm. search uses tsvector.

Answer (score 1):

Search has the advantage of allowing search for multiple fields:

```
>>> Entry.objects.annotate(
...     search=SearchVector('blog__tagline', 'body_text'),
... ).filter(search='cheese')
[
    <Entry: Cheese on Toast recipes>,
    <Entry: Pizza Recipes>,
    <Entry: Dairy farming in Argentina>,
]
```